# como trabalhar com diferentes dimensão no android studio?

Tags: android, layout-responsivo

Gostaria de adaptar meu aplicativo criado para cada modelo de celular.
Como eu alguns ele fica com o texto menor na tela e em outros maior, eu gostaria de criar um método onde ele ele se adapte ao modelo do celular que a pessoa esta..
que ele sempre fique do tamanho ideal para aquele celular

Sei que tem em haver com ldpi, mdpi, xxhdpi, etc. Mas não sei como gerar esse arquivo dimens.xml.

Comment: Eu me deparei com essa resposta recentemente. Deve servir para você também. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como suportar vários tipos de ecrãs/telas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191633/como-suportar-v%c3%a1rios-tipos-de-ecr%c3%a3s-telas)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, da uma pesquisada sobre densidades de telas. https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?hl=pt-br esse link é da documentação do próprio android e aborda esse assunto.

Só um pequeno resumo:
O android trabalha com uma unidade de dp diferente de um HTLM ou CSS  que utilizamos px ou %. Cada tela tem sua densidade especifica. Lembra de salvar as imagens corretamente que tu não vai ter grande problemas.

Espero ter ajudado