# Como suportar vários tipos de ecrãs/telas

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-responsivo

Iniciei-me em Android há pouco tempo (autodidacta) e deparei-me com a seguinte situação: suporte a vários ecrãs.

Vi alguns tutoriais e dúvidas de outras pessoas mas não encontrei nada que me ajudasse com certos aspectos.

As minhas dúvidas são:

- Por exemplo na imagem que eu tenho em cima 250dp x 250dp (ecrã default), como é que posso fazer para a imagem dar para os outros layout's (small, large, xlarge)? Tenho de redimensionar manualmente?
- Depois segundo o que entendi, há rácios para calcular os dp's para outros ecrãs? estou correto?
- Nos botões registar e entrar, estão dentro de um existe maneira de ajudar tudo aquilo à tela, caso aumente ou encolha ? Pois, por exemplo, no large existe vários tamanhos de ecrã.

Deixo as imagens abaixo.

Se alguém me pudesse esclarecer as minhas dúvidas agradecia e que me indicasse pelo que tenho de pesquisar.

[image: Normal]

[image: Noutro ecra]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_Base"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#5E554A">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_Imagem"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView_Logo"
            android:src="@drawable/LOGO"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20.0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView_Bem_vindo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Bem-Vindo"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:background="#81BC41"
            android:textColor="#5E554A"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="CARTÃO DESPERTAR"
            android:id="@+id/button_Cartao_Despertar"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColor="#81BC41"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="inherit"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="PRODUTOS"
            android:id="@+id/button_Produtos"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#81BC41" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="LISTA DE COMPRAS"
            android:id="@+id/button_Lista_compras"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColor="#81BC41"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="inherit" />
        <Button
            android:text="PROMOÇÕES"
            android:id="@+id/button_Promocoes"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColor="#81BC41"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="ESTADO DE ENCOMENDAS"
            android:id="@+id/button_Encomendas"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColor="#81BC41"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="inherit"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="REGISTAR-ME"
            android:id="@+id/button_Registo"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:textColor="#81BC41"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="inherit"
            android:padding="15px"
            android:layout_margin="10px"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="INICIAR SESSÃO"
            android:id="@+id/button_Log_In"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="15px"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:textColor="#81BC41"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="inherit"
            android:layout_margin="10px"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

O tema "suporte a vários ecrãs/telas", apesar de não ser complexo, contém muitos aspectos pelo que se torna difícil abordá-lo de forma completa, no formato de resposta do stackoverflow.

Irei abordar apenas os aspectos que julgo serem os mais relevantes para o seu entendimento.

### Características da tela.

- **Tamanho da tela(*Screen size*)** - É medida da diagonal da tela, expressa em polegadas(*inch*).

  O Android define quatro grupos para o tamanho de tela:

  - pequena(*small*)
  - normal(*normal*)
  - grande(*large*)
  - extra grande(*xlarge*).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Resolução da tela(*Screen Resolution*)** - Número de pixeis que a tela contém.
- **Densidade da tela(*Screen density*)** - Calculada em função das anteriores, é a razão entre um determinado número de pixeis e o tamanho ocupado por eles na tela, é expressa em dpi(*dots per inch*).

  O Android define 6 grupos para a densidade da tela:

  - baixa(*ldpi*)
  - média(*mdpi*)
  - alta(*hdpi*)
  - extra-alta(*xhdpi*)
  - extra-extra-alta(*xxhdpi*)
  - extra-extra-extra-alta(*xxxhdpi*).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Conceitos.

- **Orientação da tela(Screen Orientation)** - A orientação da tela em relação ao usuário:

  - vertical/retrato(*portraint*)
  - horinzontal/paisagem(*landscape*).
- **Pixel independente de densidade(*Density-independent pixel*)** - Expressa em dp, é uma unidade "virtual" que permite que os valores das dimensões sejam interpretados de forma a ocuparem o mesmo espaço físico, qualquer que seja a densidade da tela.
  1dp é equivalente a um pixel físico em uma tela de 160 dpi, que é a densidade de uma tela de densidade média(mdpi).
  Ao expressar as dimensões em dp o sistema irá desenhar as *views* de forma a terem a mesma dimensão física, independentemente da densidade da tela.

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

  Se a dimensão for expressa em pixeis(px) o tamanho real das views diminuirá com o aumento da densidade.

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- **Pixels escaláveis(*scalable pixels*)** - Expressa em sp, é o equivalente a dp para a dimensão de textos.
- **Qualificadores de configuração** - Um qualificador é uma string usado no nome das pastas de recursos, no projeto Android, para especificar a configuração para o qual os recursos devem ser usados.
  O sistema escolherá, entre os recursos disponíveis, o mais adequado para as características da tela do dispositivo.

### Suportar múltiplas telas.

#### Layouts responsivos(adaptáveis).

Na grande maioria das situações, o suporte a múltiplas telas é conseguido automaticamente pelo sistema se, ao desenhar o layout, escolher os atributos e dimensões criteriosamente.

- **Dimensões** - Use preferencialmente `"wrap_content"` e/ou `"match_parent"`.
  Principalmente `"match_parent"`, que permite às views ajustarem o seu tamanho ao espaço disponível.

  Num LinearLayout, use `android:layout_weight` para distribuir proporcionalmente o espaço existente que cada view deve ocupar.

  Se tiver de usar um valor fixo, use sempre a unidade dp ou sp.
- **Posicionamento** - Para que o posicionamento das views se ajuste às dimensões disponíveis deve posicioná-las umas em relação às outras, recorrendo a atributos do tipo `android:layout_alignParentLeft` e `android:layout_below`, no caso de RealtiveLayout, ou `android:layout_gravity` e `android:layout_weight` num LinearLayout.

  Não use margens para posicionar views. Margens devem ser usadas apenas para criar um espaço envolvente.

  Para layouts grandes e complexos considere usar o novo [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html). Nele o posicionamento é definido com relações entre as views. É mais flexível do que RelativeLayout e mais fácil de usar com o Editor de Layout do Android Studio.

#### Layouts alternativos

Devido à grande variedade de dimensões das telas existente e à orientação em que está a ser usada, nem sempre se obtém os resultados pretendidos apenas com a adaptabilidade do *layout*.
No caso de telas pequenas, por não haver espaço suficiente. Nas telas muito grandes, por mau aproveitamento do espaço existente.
Nesses casos devem ser disponibilizados *layouts* alternativos.

Os layouts alternativos deverão de ser colocados em pastas usando, no seu nome, o [qualificador de configuração](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) para a qual se destinam.

Para qualificar uma configuração pode usar mais de um qualificador.
Por exemplo, um *layout* para ser usado numa tela ldpi na orientação horizontal/paisagem deve ser colocado na pasta com o nome *res/layout-land-ldpi*.

Para evitar repetição de código, coloque as partes comuns do *layout* em arquivos separados e use `<include layout=""/>` no *layout* final.

#### Bitmaps alternativos

Ao adaptar as dimensões das ImageView em função da densidade da tela, o sistema necessita de redimensionar as imagens de forma a serem renderizados para o tamanho físico adequado. Esse redimensionamento poderá provocar perdas de qualidade da imagem.
Para garantir que a qualidade se mantém, devem ser disponibilizadas versões alternativas para cada densidade de tela.

Os *bitmaps* alternativos devem ser colocados em pastas usando, no seu nome, o qualificador de densidade para a qual se destinam.

Deverá criar na pasta `\res` novas pastas drawable, uma para cada densidade, na forma `drawable-xxx`, onde `xxxx` é:

- ldpi
- mdpi
- hdpi
- xhdpi
- xxhdpi

O tamanho das imagens, a incluir em cada uma delas, é calculado multiplicando as dimensões da imagem na pasta *res/drawable-mdpi* pelo valor resultante da formula `factor = dpi/160`.

Os factores a aplicar para as densidades comuns são:

- ldpi => 0.75
- mdpi => 1
- hdpi => 1.5
- xhdpi => 2
- xxhdpi => 3

No caso de *icons*, a usar nas várias partes da interface do usuário, e de forma a manter consistência entre aplicativos, consulte a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) para, além de outros aspectos a ter em conta, saber quais as dimensões a usar.

O Android Studio disponibiliza o [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html?utm_source=android-studio#about) que, partindo de uma imagem inicial, gera automaticamente as outras para cada uma das resoluções habitualmente usadas.

### Notas finais.

- Quando criar/manipular layouts em java tenha em atenção que a maioria(eu diria todos mas não tenho a certeza) dos métodos usam dimensões expressas em pixeis. Antes de os usar converta os valores dp para pixeis.

  Para fazer essa conversão pode usar o seguinte método:

  ```
  public static int convertDpToPixels(float dp, Activity context){

      DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
      context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
      float density = metrics.density;
      return (int) Math.ceil(dp * density);
  }
  ```
- [Crie emuladores](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html) para os tipos mais comuns de telas e teste os seus *layouts*. Apesar de não serem 100% fiáveis, permitem detectar a maioria dos problemas.
- Mantenha os *layouts* simples. Não só são mais fáceis de gerir como proporcionam uma melhor experiência ao usuário.
- Leia a documentação dos vários tipos de ViewGroup disponíveis de forma a conhecer bem os atributos disponíveis para o posicionamento das views.

### Referências.

- [Compatibilidade com várias telas](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
- [Fornecimento de recursos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).
- [Units & measurements](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html#).
- [Criar e gerenciar dispositivos virtuais](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html).
- [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).
- [Icon Design Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html).

Answer (score 1):

Também me deparei com o mesmo problema, e após várias tentativas, na minha opinião o melhor é criar um layout por cada tipo de ecrã.

Quando está  a editar o seu layout clique no botão do lado direito de "**Language**" logo em cima do próprio layout e selecione **"Create other..."**

Será apresentada uma página, na qual mantém o Directory Name.

Depois em **Available qualifiers** passe a variável **size** para o lado direito e depois é só escolher o tamanho. ele irá criar um novo layout com o mesmo desenho do antigo e aí bastará adaptar os tamanhos para esse ecrã.

Terá de ter em atenção que quando alterar algum id num layout, terá de alterar em todos, senão poderão ocorrer erros ao executar o programa.

Comment: Vale também lembrar que na construção do layout, determinando `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`..etc, pode-se aplicar algumas estratégias para controlar este problema, evitando deixar tamanhos fixos nos componentes e apenas "relacionando entre eles".. Claro, mas isto é alguns casos... Para não precisar replicar o layout várias vezes.. Isto vária da complexidade da sua `activity`

Comment: Nem sempre fica assim, algumas coisas adaptam-se mas nem tudo, como tipos de letra, etc..