# Como organizar corretamente o DP e DPI para cada tipo de tela no Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Existe algum tipo de fórmula ou jeito de saber os seguintes quesitos sem precisar ficar "buildando" toda hora para verificar?

- Como saber se aquela Imagem/Texto/Botão ou seja o que for fica visivelmente bom para o usuário na determinada tela que tem um tipo de dpi?
- Como saber qual é o dp que eu preciso para alinhar a Imagem/Texto/Botão ou seja oque for para ficar corretamente no (Header, Footer, Centro, Direita ou Esquerda) corretamente para cada tela.

O conhecimento que eu tenho é o seguinte:

> - ldpi (baixa) ~ 120 dpi
> - mdpi (média) ~ 160 dpi
> - hdpi (alta) ~ 240 dpi
> - xhdpi (extra-alta) ~ 320 dpi
> - xxhdpi (extra-extra-alta) ~ 480 dpi
> - xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-alta) ~ 640 dpi
>
> **Pixel independente de densidade (dp):** A conversão das unidades de pixel em pixels de tela é simples: px = dp * (dpi / 160)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Existe algum tipo de fórmula ou jeito de saber os seguintes quesitos sem precisar ficar "buildando" toda hora para verificar?

Não existe "fórmula" mas existe um jeito de saber sem *"precisar ficar "buildando" toda hora"*.

Na Toolbar da aba do Editor de *layouts* do Android Studio tem a opção de escolher o dispositivo usado para fazer o *render* do *layout*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É assim possível verificar como o layout é apresentado em vários dispositivos. Existe também a possibilidade de escolher a orientação do dispositivo, a versão do Android e o *Theme* a aplicar.

O uso da unidade dp ou dpi(que são a mesma coisa) garante que views, margins, padding, etc sejam renderizadas com as mesmas dimensões, qualquer que seja a densidade da tela do dispositivo.
Isso garante que, por exemplo, um botão tenha as dimensões necessárias para poder ser clicado ou que o conteúdo duma imagem possa ser perceptível, qualquer que seja a densidade de tela.

Outra questão é a existência de diferentes tamanhos de tela. São as dimensões dela que determinam o número de *views* que se conseguem colocar tanto na vertical como na horizontal, podendo haver situações que será necessária a criação de *layouts* alternativos.

Como complemento veja [Como suportar vários tipos de ecrãs/telas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191633/2541).

Comment: eu entendo em relação ao verificar sem compilar utilizando o preview do editor de layous no próprio Android Stúdio. Porém o problema é que estou utilizando um SDK de Realidade Aumentada chamada vuforia. E no layout a tela é toda preta, pois estou utilizando um layout de "camera" onde a camera do celular fica ligado. Não tenho como verificar pelo Layout e nem pelo AVD, pois o AVD ele builda certinho porém não abre o emulador, não acontece nada. Como consertar isto?

Comment: Não tenho nenhuma experiência com o vuforia, por isso não posso ajudá-lo. Exponha esse problema em uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Mas o conceito de DP é justamente feito pra isso, manter o mesmo tamanho das views entre diferentes resoluções de tela. Por exemplo, se você tem aparelhos com a mesma proporção de tela (por exemplo, 16:9) mas resoluções diferentes, as view sempre irão aparecer do mesmo tamanho. Claro que em aparelhos com proporções de tela diferente, tipo um tablet, que não necessariamente é 16:9, as views não irão mudar de tamanho, mas irá sobrar ou faltar tela em relação ao app rodando numa tela com proporção diferente.

Você pode testar diversas configurações de tela no próprio Android Studio sem compilar. Na tela de preview do editor de layouts você sempre pode trocar o aparelho target na combobox dessa janela que mostra o nome de um aparelho.

Comment: eu entendo em relação ao verificar sem compilar utilizando o preview do editor de layous no próprio Android Stúdio. Porém o problema é que estou utilizando um SDK de Realidade Aumentada chamada vuforia. E no layout a tela é toda preta, pois estou utilizando um layout de "camera" onde a camera do celular fica ligado. Não tenho como verificar pelo Layout e nem pelo AVD, pois o AVD ele builda certinho porém não abre o emulador, não acontece nada. Como consertar isto?