# Como funciona a utilização dos Layouts e Redimencionamentos de DPI?

Tags: android, android-layout

No **Android** existem os chamados "**DPI**", que são **densidades por pixel**. **Cada tela** tem seu tipo de **DPI** como por exemplo:

> **Smartphones:**
>
> - **layout** [?]
> - **layout-ldpi** [240x320 & 240x400]
> - **layout-mdpi** [320x480 & 480x854]
> - **layout-hdpi** [480x800 & 480x854]
> - **layout-xhdpi** [720x1280]
> - **layout-xxhdpi** [1080x1920]
> - **layout-xxxhdpi** [?]
>
> Tablets:
>
> - **layout-mdpi** [600x1024 & 800x1280]
> - **layout-xhdpi** [2560x1800 | 2560x1600 | 2048x1536 & 1200x1920]
> - **layout-tvhdpi** [800x1280]

Para **cada** tipo de **tela** existe "**pastas**" com **tamanhos de imagens** diferentes:

> - **drawable**
> - **drawable-hdpi**
> - **drawable-large**
> - **drawable-ldpi**
> - **drawable-mdpi**
> - **drawable-xhdpi**
> - **drawable-xxhdpi**
> - **drawable-xxxhdpi**

**As minhas dúvidas são a seguinte:**

> > **1)** Em cada pasta de layout, eu crio arquivos com o mesmo nome de .xml
> >     para a tela. Porém como eu sei que o android está utilizando a tela
> >     naquele determinado DPI? È algum código que eu tenho que inserir para
> >     ele utilizar os layouts?
> >
> > **2)** Para que serve a pasta "layout" e "drawable" com o nome "puro", sem utilizar como por exemplo "layout-ldpi"? Nesta mesma pergunta, quais são os tamanhos das imagens na pasta "drawable puro" e "layout puro"?
> >
> > **3)** Supondo que eu tenho que criar um background, landscape e portrait na resolução 800x600. O portrait é 800x600 e é claro que o landscape é 600x800. Eu devo criar o background nestas duas resoluções? E como essas imagens seram chamadas corretamente pelo Android?
> >
> > **4)** Seguindo o raciocío da questão **(3)**, para cada tipo de resolução, como eu sei qual é o tamanho em px ideal para imagens como por exemplo, icons, imagens "normais" e outros?
> >
> > **5)** Caso eu queira criar "layouts" específicos como por exemplos para o tipo de dpi "sw600dp". O que eu devo fazer?
> >
> > **6)** Seguindo o raciocínio da questão **(5)**, é necessário realmente criar estes tipos de "layouts" personalizados, ou somente os dpi que eu citei acima já bastão?
> >
> > **7)** Como funciona a criação de layouts para tablets? E como eu faço a "junção" de layouts" de tablets com os dos "smartphones" dentro de um mesmo projeto do Android?
> >
> > **8)** Existem também as pastas do tipo "values", "values-v21", "values-v22". Para que serve essas pastas e o que deve ser inseridas em cada uma delas?

Agradeço pela paciência, e peço por gentileza para seguirem a ordem das perguntas para que não haja confusão.

Comment: Relacionado(talvez duplicata?): [Como suportar vários tipos de ecrãs/telas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191633/2541)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) O Android sabe a resolução do aparelho e automaticamente escolhe a pasta (se existirem criadas) que tem a resolução mais próxima em DPI da resolução detectada. Se não houver uma pasta com a resolução definida no nome, ele pega a pasta normal mesmo, no caso de layouts, a pasta "layout".

2) Quanto ao nome puro, significa que ela é a pasta default, ou seja, o Android vai consultar essa pasta apenas se não existir as pastas correspondentes com qualificadores que se apliquem, como a "layout-ldpi" que você citou, se o telefone for LDPI e essa pasta existir, ele vai usar os arquivos dela primeiro, caso contrário, vai usar da pasta pura. Se você não for criar imagens para diferentes resoluções (e salvar nas respectivas pastas), guarde em "drawable" a imagem com a maior resolução possível.

3) Pela mesma lógica das respostas acima. Você cria uma pasta "drawable-land" e guarda as imagens em landscape com o mesmo nome das imagens equivalentes para portrait que estarão simplesmente em "drawable". Em tempo de execução o Android vai pegar a imagem da pasta certa, porque ele saberá em que orientação o aparelho vai estar e vai usar o mesmo princípio da resposta acima, de tentar combinar o cenário atual que o app se encontra com o nome da pasta que melhor atenderia o cenário.

4) Você tem que definir qual o tamanho em DP's a imagem vai ocupar no layout, depois converte esse valor para pixels quando for gerar as imagens finais para cada resolução (XXHDPI, LDPI, etc). Faça uma busca rápida no Google, tem vários sites que mostram a fórmula de cálculo ou mesmo já convertem e geram imagens para as diversas resoluções em DP que o app vai funcionar.

5) Mesma lógica de sempre, cria uma pasta "layout-sw600dp" e cria um XML com o mesmo nome do arquivo que vai rodar na resolução padrão, o que está na pasta "layout".

6) Criar layouts personalizados para diversas resoluções sempre darão uma experiência melhor para o usuário, visto que você controla como o seu app será exibido em diversos tamanhos de tela. Seguem algumas boas práticas nesse site: https://material.io/guidelines/

7) Respondido na 5, mas dependendo da diferença de componentes entre um layout de celular e tablet para a mesma Activity, você vai precisar tratar isso no código da Activity.

8) A pasta "values" serve para definir e organizar dados que tem grande chance de serem reutilizados em várias partes do app, então ficará mais fácil de dar manutenção nos mesmos por estarem isolados do código, por exemplo, Strings (ficam no strings.xml), Temas para Views (ficam no styles.xml), dimensões (ficam no dimens.xml) e por aí vai. Esses quantificadores numéricos são para especificar que a pasta deverá ser usada para uma determinada versão da API ou superior e podem ser utilizados em qualquer outra pasta de recurso além do "values", como o "layout", "drawable", etc. Por exemplo, se você quer que um determinado valor inteiro seja X em API's 21 (Lollipop) ou maior, coloca ele na pasta "values-v21", caso contrário será usado o valor que estiver na pasta "value" pura. O mesmo vale para um layout, por exemplo, caso você queira usar algum componente que só rode apartir do Nougat, então você criaria um layout em "layout-v23".

Aqui estão boas explicações sobre isso tudo:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?hl=pt-br
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Recomendo também dar uma olhada nesse curso. Por acaso fiz essa semana (é bem curto) e responde todas as suas perguntas.

https://www.udacity.com/course/material-design-for-android-developers--ud862

Esse aqui também é excelente:

https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-user-interface--ud834

Ambos são cursos oficiais da Google.