# Como fazer telas proporcionais em celulares diferentes no Android?

Tags: android, imagem, layout

Estou apanhando um bocado pra conseguir essa resposta, então quem sabe alguém por aqui pode me dar uma ajudinha...

Preciso colocar em uma determinada tela, uma imagem de fundo, e uma série de botões superpostos a esta imagem, alinhados com determinadas posições da imagem. Quando dimensiono tudo para o meu celular (no caso, um Motorola Moto G4 Plus), consigo ajeitar tudo certinho. Mas se rodo num emulador de outro celular, como por exemplo num Nexus 5, os botões já caem em lugares diferentes...

Procurei utilizar o recurso do ConstraintLayout, para que as referências dos botões fossem "amarradas" nos limites da imagem de fundo, mas não deu certo... Alguém já fez algo parecido?

Para exemplificar melhor, vou colocar aqui um trecho do meu código. Primeiro, o xml que representa essa tela:

```html
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/flByCapo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGuitar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/guitar_arm" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tvByCapo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/strChangeCapo"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivGuitar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b0"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="194dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivGuitar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivGuitar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="149dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivGuitar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivGuitar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="178dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivGuitar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivGuitar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="202dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivGuitar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivGuitar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="226dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivGuitar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivGuitar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="248dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivGuitar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivGuitar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="269dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivGuitar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivGuitar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="289dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivGuitar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivGuitar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Trata-se de uma imagem de um braço de violão, e sobre ele coloquei pequenos botões pretos, simulando capotrastes (para quem não é músico, trata-se de uma ferramenta que pressiona as cordas em posições variadas do braço do instrumento, para alterar o tom da música), cada um numa posição. Por código eu controlo qual botão deve aparecer e quais ficam "quase" invisíveis. O problema é que, quando no meu celular fica tudo certinho, se testo em outro tamanho de tela, os botões caem em lugares errados, fora da imagem do braço do violão...

Agradeço se alguém puder dar uma ajuda!

Comment: Com algum trabalho e engenho talvez consiga. Leia as respostas à pergunta [Como suportar vários tipos de ecrãs/telas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191633/2541).

Answer (score 0):

Olá! 
Para utilizar a compatibilidade em outros celulares, normalmente não se utiliza espaços fixos. Por exemplo, nesse trecho de código (trecho abaixo) as margens que você está dando podem ficar boas para a tela do seu celular, porém para celulares menores, ou até maiores, essas margens tem tamanhos bem diferentes...

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/b6"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="269dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
    android:background="@drawable/capo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivGuitar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivGuitar" />
```

Para ter uma responsividade para telas de tamanhos diferentes, aconselho a utilizar sempre os atributos, match_parent, wrap_content e pesos para layouts. No seu caso, como você quer fazer uma tela bem dinâmica, você pode trabalhar com frame layout e constraint layout, já que são modos em que você consegue alocar objetos em vários lugares da tela e que tem uma responsividade para vários tamanhos de telas.

Dê uma olhada nesse link: 
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/