# Dúvida com densidade dpi(dp) correta

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu sou iniciante em desenvolvimento de app Android, e estou com uma dúvida simples.

Os números de dpi na imagem abaixo, são também o máximo que uma img pode ter em width & height(dp) em suas respectivas densidades... Certo?

Se for isso, então eu posso diminuir esse dp da forma que eu quiser, só não pode ultrapassar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não. A densidade da tela(Screen density)(dpi) não limita o valor máximo a usar em width & height(dp).

Uma tela tem duas características:

- **Tamanho da tela(Screen size)** - Representa a medida real da diagonal da tela, é expressa em polegadas(inch).
- **Resolução da tela(Screen Resolution)** - Número de pixeis que a tela contém.

A densidade da tela é resultado dessas características.
O seu valor é a razão entre um determinado número de pixeis e o tamanho ocupado por eles na tela, é expressa em dpi(dots per inch).

Outra coisa é a unidade *dp* usada no width e height.

*dp* é uma unidade "virtual" que permite que os valores das dimensões sejam interpretados de forma a ocuparem o mesmo espaço físico, qualquer que seja a densidade da tela.
1dp é equivalente a um pixel físico em uma tela de 160 dpi. 160 dpi é a densidade de uma tela de densidade média(mdpi).
Ao expressar as dimensões em *dp* o sistema irá desenhar as *views* de forma a terem a mesma dimensão real/física, independentemente da densidade da tela.

Como complemento veja [Como suportar vários tipos de ecrãs/telas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191633/2541).