# Layout diferente para retrato(portraint) e paisagem(landscape)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tenho o seguinte:

```
package carcleo.com.cadastro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Principal extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();

        if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            setContentView(R.layout.principal);
        }else{
            setContentView(R.layout.principal(land));
        }

    }
}
```

No `if`, verifico a *rotação* da tela para exibir o **layout** correto.

Porém, na pasta `res`, tem 2 arquivos **principal.xml**

O `principal.xml`e o `principal.xml(land)`

Dessa forma, não estou sabendo como chamar o **layout** quando a rotação for **LANDSCAPE**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

TELA DA **LAND**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da **LAND**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".Principal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/login" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Usuário"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_senha"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Senha"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="414dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="414dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:text="Novo Cadastro" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado se já alterei

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();

            if (configuration.orientation == 
Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                setContentView(R.layout.principal);
            }else{
                setContentView(R.layout.principal(land));
            }

        }
```

por

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();

        setContentView(R.layout.principal);

    }
```

?

No dispositivo e em **LANDSCAPE** os elementos estão ficando um abaixo do outro e não ao lado como na aba de **design**

Vejam o **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="carcleo.com.cadastro">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Principal">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Cadastro" />
        <activity android:name=".Resposta"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não necessita de fazer essa verificação.

O sistema Android automaticamente carregará o layout existente na pasta *land* quando o dispositivo for rodado para a orientação *landscape*.

Comment: Então basta fazer setContentView(R.layout.principal); e funciona?

Comment: Adicionei mais detalhes no final da pergunta pois ainda os elementos se mostram de forma errada no (é só no) dispositivo

Comment: eu devo estar fazendo alguma coisa errada pois limpei todo o layout  LANDSCAPE. Recompilei e lancei no dispositivo Sim, excluiu ele antes de reinstalar, e ao girar a tela ele ainda exibe os itens como se estivesse apenas virando o layout PORT

Comment: *Então basta fazer setContentView(R.layout.principal); e funciona?* - Sim. basta isso. Quando se refere a "dispositivo", está a referir-se a que tipo de dispositivo? Note que no *preview* do editor está seleccionado um Nexus 4.

Comment: ah sim. O dispositivo que me refiro é físico. Um Moto G 4 Play. Não estou usando emulador não, Estou jogando direto no aparelho celular. Parece que não está sendo chamada a tela de landscape. Parece que o que ocorre é que a PORT está sendo girada na LAND

Comment: As características da tela do Moto G 4 são iguais à do Nexus 4? Se não são é natural que o que vê no Moto G 4 seja diferente do que vê no *preview* do editor.

Comment: Bom, deixa ei ver se entendi: Na tela do Android Studio, está Nexus 4. Mas na hora de compilar e abre o AVD, então eu escolho o meu Moto G. Não é assim não? Precisa escolhe moto g no Android Studio também?

Comment: Não. O preview mostra como o seu layout é apresentado num Nexus 4, se a tela do Moto G tiver características diferentes o layout pode ser apresentado de forma diferente, Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/191684/2541)

Comment: Então. Fiz o seguinte. Criei um projeto novo apensas com uma Activity. E nela, coloquei os 2 layout's com um botão apenas. Na retrato, coloquei RETRATO na caption do Button e na paisagem, coloquei PAISAGEM na caption do buttom. Funcionou corretamente.Porém,ao fazer essas modificações no projeto antigo, ele apenas exibe o layout PORT. Ele não está chamando o layout-land. Porém, como a sua explicação funcionou em um projeto novo e vazio. Então vou dá-la como a solução! Obrigado!