# Imagens para diferentes tamanhos de telas android

Tags: android, layout, drawable

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que utiliza a camera no android.

Sobre o FrameLayout onde exibo a camera coloquei um LinearLayout com um background conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é o seguinte:

Criei essa imagem no tamanho 720 x 1280 pixels, ou seja, com a resolução da tela do meu celular. Funcionou perfeitamente.

Quando fui testar em outro celular com a resolução de tela de 480 x 800 pixels, o background ficou distorcido conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisando, encontrei vários tutoriais falando sobre as pastas **drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi**, com suporte para várias densidades de telas. Mas não entendi como trabalhar com isso e também não sei como adicionar essas pastas no meu projeto, pois, no Android Studio só tem a pasta **drawable** padrão.

Por favor, alguém me ajude!?

Comment: Eu ia te responder detalhando, mas como marcaram como pendente não tem como. Pra te ajudar instale o plugin no android studio chamado Android Drawable Importer, eu utilizo ele por ser bem simples. Aqui tem um tutorial em inglês de como instalar e usar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbFLDR6X2D8

Comment: Entendi Murillo. Legal, gostei do plugi, parece bem simples e prático de usar mesmo. Dúvida, como eu criei a imagem padrão em 720 x 1280 px, quando eu importar essa imagem pelo plugin ele vai criar as outras resoluções automaticamente desta imagem?

Comment: Sim, você escolhe quais as resoluções que vai querer, e o plugin ja adapta a imagem pra cada resolução e elas ficarão na pasta drawable dentro de um pacote com o nome da imagem e dentro desse pacote ficará todas as imagens com as diferentes resoluções.

Comment: Relacionado/duplicata: [Como suportar vários tipos de ecrãs/telas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191633/2541)

Comment: Não é necessário qualquer plugin. O Android Studio tem o [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html?utm_source=android-studio#about) para esse propósito.